# jQuery: get inline style not CSS of body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the real style of an inline element but it's always getting the css applied to it. I don't want to modify my CSS, too many pages depend on it.

```
<body class="processed" style="padding-top: 157px ;margin-top: 0px;">
```

My CSS

```
.processed{padding-top: 56px !important;}
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    var pad = $('body').css('padding-top');
    $('body').attr('style','padding-top:'+ pad +' !important; margin-top: 0px;');
   console.log('pad' + pad);    

});
```

The result: `body` with inline style `56px`, instead of `157px`...

Comment: The inline style is the CSS, it is just inline CSS. What are you asking?

Comment: Javascript modifying CSS is always getting what the current calculated styles on the elements are. If you have 100 class rules, it' won't show the css for all the classes, rather the one css rule the element is currently obeying due to the [css specificity rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

Comment: by adding `!important` to your css you override the inline style therefore it will be 56px.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith yes it does

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith thats because you already put an `!important` tag in the inline style, and inline style is stronger than class styling. but in op's case there is no `!important` tag in the inline `padding-top` therefore the class `padding-top` overrides the inline one.

Comment: I know !important override the css style, but I'm not able to modify the inline behavior 'cause a third party service is doing it (sumome). I just need the inline value and later force the style to be Important with that style inline value(157px not the 56px style).. So i'm trying to get the 157 and set later in jquery. Am I clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, the problem was an script overriding styles after DOM ready...the !important played a good role..

Answer (score 1):

You could create a second "important" class in the CSS file, so it wouldn't affect those other pages, but it would override that first "important" class.

You just have to write that new class after the first one.

For example:

HTML:

```
<body class="processed processed-large-top">
```

CSS:

```
.processed{padding-top: 56px !important;}
.processed-large-top{padding-top: 157px !important; margin-top: 0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

A CSS rule with **!important** have higher priority than inline styles. To override it, you have to use **!important** also on the inline style CSS.

So, your HTML tag have to end up like this:

```
<body class="processed" style="padding-top: 157px !important;margin-top: 0px;">
```